# error filtering templat: Template file 'header.html' is not found in mail in magento 2.4.6

Tags: module, email, template, custom, magento2.4.6

Send invoice email to custom mail address in magento 2 but
create custom email template but face this issue in magento 2.4.6

> app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/email_templates/invoice_email_template.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
       <template id="invoice_email_template" label="Invoice Email Template" file="invoice_email_template.html" type="html" module="YourVendor_YourModule" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

> invoice_email_template.html

```
    {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
     <table>
        <tr class="email-intro">
          <td>
           Email: {{var email}}
          </td>
           <td>
           Name: {{var name}}
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

   {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

magento default use html Invoice for your Main Website Store order

Invoice_new.html but not working any suggestion for that

advance thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create new email template, then follow this steps.

1. Register the new email template with `email_templates.xml` like this.

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/etc/email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="Your_Custom_Template_ID" label="Your_Custom_Template_LABEL" file="invoice_email_template.html" type="html" area="frontend" module="Vendor_Extension"/>
</config>
```

2. Then create that html file `invoice_email_template.html` like this.

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/view/frontend/email/invoice_email_template.html

```
<!--@subject YOUR_SUBJECT@-->
<!--@vars
YOUR_Custom_Variables
@-->
<body>
...............
...............
YOUR CUSTOM CODE
...............
...............
</body>
```

So in this way, it by default added magento Header and Footer.

Comment: new email template but same as send email invoice button click in invoice section how to same template use differnt file @Dhiren Vasoya

Comment: If you have different question, then ask separately, so other can also help you into that.
If my answer help you accept as solution and upvote, so it help other into community as well.

Comment: above question alreday send invoice mail regarding @Dhiren Vasoya

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala there is not any code related to send email into your question. The question is about Email header missing not about email sending code.